# Remove duplicate rows of a matrix or dataframe

Tags: r

I want to check which rows of the matrix or dataframe are duplicate, how can we find it?

We want to remove duplicate rows. Duplicate rows are rows which have the same values in both columns 1 and 2 by ignoring their ordering.

For example, for the following matrix:

```
Col1   Col2     database 
 A       B       IntAct
 A       B       Bind
 B       A       BioGrid
```

I want to have only one of the rows.

```
Col1   Col2     database 
 A       B       IntAct
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option using `pmax/pmin`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!duplicated(pmin(Col1, Col2), pmax(Col1, Col2))]
#   Col1 Col2 database
#1:    A    B   IntAct
```

Benchmarking with bigger data:

```
# dummy data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Col1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 Col2 = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 database = sample(c("IntAct", "Bind", "BioGrid"), 1000,
                                   replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  t = df[ !duplicated(t(apply(df[, 1:2], 1, sort))), ] ,
  paste = df[ !duplicated(apply(df[, 1:2], 1,
                                function(i)paste(sort(i), collapse = ","))), ],
  pmin = df[ !duplicated(cbind(pmin(df[, 1], df[, 2]), pmax(df[, 1], df[, 2]))), ],
  times = 1000)

# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#      t 33.49008 36.337253 38.374825 37.420015 39.610627 153.89251  1000   b
#  paste 33.24177 36.102055 38.079015 37.330498 39.465803 151.43734  1000   b
#   pmin  2.59116  2.790864  3.034999  2.910316  3.137389  11.99905  1000  a
```

Answer (score 4):

A wordy alternative using `sqldf`:

**First row**
We create an id column to get the first ocurrence.

```
library(sqldf)
df$id <- seq.int(nrow(df))
sqldf("select col1, col2, database, min(id) id
      from (select col1, col2, database, id from df where col1 <= col2
      union all
      select col2 col1, col1 col2, database, id from df where col1 > col2) 
      group by col1, col2")
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 database id
1    A    B   IntAct  1
```

**Last row** (third in this example)
A more concise option proposed by G. Grothendieck

```
sqldf("select col1, col2, database 
      from (select col1, col2, database from df where col1 <= col2 
      union all 
      select col2 col1, col1 col2, database from df where col1 > col2) 
      group by col1, col2")
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 database
1    A    B  BioGrid
```

Comment: Nothing against `sqldf`, but I think for this case, it is a bit overkill.

Comment: @zx8754 I agree. I just did it for the sake of reference, maybe useful for those coming from SQL.

Comment: In sqlite one could avoid defining an id column.  This is slightly shorter:  `library(sqldf); sqldf("select col1, col2, database
      from (select col1, col2, database from df where col1 <= col2
      union all
      select col2 col1, col1 col2, database from df where col1 > col2) 
      group by col1, col2")`

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck I added an id column to get the first occurrence (not the 3rd row) of the data frame as asked by OP.

Comment: The question specifies "one of the rows", not the first row.

Comment: But the one of the rows he chose was the first. Now, thanks to your contribution, any visitor can choose from the two options. I will add your comment to the answer so it's clearer.Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
d[!(duplicated(d[,1:2]) | rev(duplicated(d[rev(rownames(d)), 1:2]))),]
  Col1 Col2 database
1    A    B   IntAct
```

`duplicated` shows rows that match one with a lower index.  That's not quite enough, but applying it on the data frame both top-to-bottom and bottom-to-top gives what you want.

Comment: When I add a new row to the matrix, it doesn't work. I ask this question for a general case, and the sample matrix is given only for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work! I need to consider rows with similar pair of values  in columns 1 and 2 (without considering their orders in the columns) as duplicated columns. (A,B) and (B,A) are duplicated. This condition should be satisfied for all rows.

Comment: This gives me the 3rd row as output.

Answer (score 3):

Paste columns together with separator, then use duplicated:

```
df[ !duplicated(apply(df[, 1:2], 1, function(i)paste(sort(i), collapse = ","))), ]
```

Comment: @Zaynab Why "seems"? It either works or not. Let us know if it doesn't work with your real data. It works for example data on your post.

Comment: @zx8754 I think you can replace the `paste(...collapse=..)` part with `t()`: `df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[, 1:2],1,sort))),]`